# WebLogic 8.1環境構築資材の入手先

Tags: linux, apache, weblogic

あるシステムのオープンソース化のため、下記の通り構成を変更することとなりました。

【現在】　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　【変更後】
OS：RedHatEnterpriseLinux　⇒　RedHatEnterpriseLinux
APサーバ：WebLogic 8.1　　　⇒　tomcat
HTTPサーバ：Apache　　　　　⇒　Apache
DB：Oracle 10g　　　　　　　　　⇒　postgres

APサーバとDBが変わるため、プログラム改修が必要となるのですがまだ修正箇所・影響範囲は特定できておりません。

調査・検討を進めるためにも環境が用意したいのですが、
開発用ドキュメントや資材は用意されておらず、手元にあるのはソース一式のみです。

ソースを確認しましたところ、「.project」ファイルを見つけeclipseのプロジェクト一式のようだったので、とりあえずeclipseにその一式を入れてみたのですが当然そのままでは動きませんでした。

エラーを確認すると、下記5件のエラーが出ておりました。

> ビルド・パスのエラーが解決されるまで、プロジェクトをビルドできません
>
> プロジェクト 'xxxxx' に、必要なライブラリー 'C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib\ojdbc14.jar'
>   がありません
>
> プロジェクト 'xxxxx' に、必要なライブラリー 'C:\bea\weblogic81\server\lib\weblogic.jar'
>   がありません
>
> プロジェクト 'xxxxx' のクラスパス変数 'JDK_TOOLS' がアンバインドされています
>
> プロジェクト 'xxxxx' のクラスパス変数 'WEBLOGIC81/webservices.jar' がアンバインドされています

エラーを解消し、自分のWindows7(32bit)上でデバックできるようにしたいのですが、
そもそもWeblogic 8.1を構築する資材が手元になく困っております。

日本オラクル様にも問い合わせを行ってみたのですが、
古いバージョンのWeblogicについてはダウンロードサイトでも公開していないとのことでした。

環境構築のため、どこかWeblogic8.1の資材を入手できるところはないものでしょうか。
また、当方WeblogicおよびLinuxの経験も全くないもので、環境構築および調査・検討を進めるにあたり参考になりそうなドキュメントやサイトはないものでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。